# How I can hide url

Tags: asp.net

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app != null)
            if (app.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/About.aspx")
                app.Context.RewritePath(
                    app.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Replace("/About.aspx", "")
                );
    }
```

I want to hide url like the following : 
requested url : "http://domain.com/WebFolder/page.aspx" 
url should be show : "http://domain.com/WebFolder"

The above code is not producing my desired result. It's causing to redirect new rewrite page. I don't want that, I just want to hide my url for section of page name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IIS [`URL Rewrite`](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) module.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways to accomplish this in mind.

One is making your page a default page under IIS.
To do this,you should select **Properties** page for your folder **WebFolder** under IIS then select default page ( default is index.html ) to your page (page.aspx),then make it top page.

Second is **ISAPI Rewriting** which is more useful.It is a free .dll.Look at this [site](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/provocative_SEF_URLs.htm) for more information.

Hope this helps
Myra